# How to launch and recover results of Maple with C++

Tags: c++, maple

I am using a C++ code which is preparing maple calculations commands sheets. OS used Ubuntu 12.04. 
I would like to launch these maple files with my C++ program and recover the results in a text file.

Do you know if there is a way doing it? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you expect the results to somehow be useful in the C++ context can we presume that the results are arrays of numeric data? If so then one approach might be to have the (worksheet) code save results to (text or binary) files. See [ExportMatrix](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ImportMatrix).

You might be able to run the worksheets using [OpenMaple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple) and, say, [system[launch]](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=system). But that might only be useful if the worksheets themselves saved the data (eg. to data file) when run.

An alternative might be to use [RunWorksheet](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DocumentTools/RunWorksheet) to run the worksheets as if they were procedures and get "return values" from the. You might be able to do that under OpenMaple.

Using .mpl text files for that Maple source (which can also be `read` into the GUI) might also make the kind of thing that you might want easier than using worksheets. Even better, when things get very involved, is having your reusable code be saved in .mla Library archives. But you may be able to get your to your goal without such refinements.

Comment: I figured that the C++ aspect was given, eg. part of a larger program, etc. Sure, simpler all round is command-line Maple interface and all worksheet operations moved to .mpl or saved in .mla. Often hard to decide whether to answer Q's exactly as asked, or to step back and examine "why are you doing it all that way?" Also possibly relevant is that RunWorksheet is a very inefficient way to call many times for many separate scalar results, say.

Answer (score 0):

Try MathLink for example. Here's a nice tutorial like pdf how you can do that: http://www.edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your this link, however this tutorial is for Mathematica and not Maple. Unfortunately, I am not using Mathematica in my project. Therefore this is not exactly what I am looking for.